# Extract first entry for each person for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table, and I am trying to select just the first "exception" for each day for each person - so for example:

```
date        agentname   exception   start   stop
01/10/2013  Smith Bob   Open Time   07:00   08:30
01/10/2013  Smith Bob   Open Time   08:45   10:45
07/10/2013  Smith Bob   Open Time   07:00   08:30
07/10/2013  Smith Bob   Open Time   08:45   10:45
08/10/2013  Smith Bob   Open Time   07:00   08:30
08/10/2013  Smith Bob   Open Time   08:45   10:45
04/10/2013  Owen John   On Loan     07:00   14:00
04/10/2013  Owen John   Break       14:00   15:00
07/10/2013  Rix Linda   Open Time   09:00   10:15
07/10/2013  Rix Linda   On Loan     11:00   11:15
```

The sql query would need to would pull out:

```
date        agentname   exception   start   stop
01/10/2013  Smith Bob   Open Time   07:00   08:30
07/10/2013  Smith Bob   Open Time   07:00   08:30
08/10/2013  Smith Bob   Open Time   07:00   08:30
04/10/2013  Owen John   On Loan     07:00   14:00
07/10/2013  Rix Linda   Open Time   09:00   10:15
```

So take Bob Smith - he has two entries on 01/10/2013 - one starting at 07:00 and one starting at 08:45 - I just want the first one pulled out (for him, and everyone else, for each day).

Can anyone advise please, how to do this in either Sql or Linq?

Thank you for your help,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to group in the inner query to get the minimum time for each day and agent.

```
 select [date], agentname, [exception], [start], [stop]
 from table1 t
 inner join
 (
    select [date], agentname, min([start]) as [start]
    from table1
    group by [date], agentname
 ) X
 on t.[date] = x.[date] and t.agentname = x.agentname and t.[start] = x.[start]
```

This will work provided that start times are unique for each day and agent.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use [ROW_NUMBER() OVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c21b4/3)

```
WITH T1 as 
(
SELECT 
     t.*,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
         (PARTITION BY [DATE],[agentname] ORDER BY [start]) as RowNumber 
     FROM T
)
   SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE RowNumber=1
   Order BY [agentname],[date]
```